# Different definitions of homotopy colimits

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, homotopy-limits

I was reading about the definition of homotopy limits and colimits, and I have seen two different approaches in "Homotopy theories and model categories" by Dwyer and Spalinski, and in "Model Categories and Their Localizations" by Hirschhorn. However I am missing the precise link between the two and in which sense they are the same concept.

The first defines the homotopy colimit functor on a generic model category $\mathcal{M}$ as the total left derived functor of the colimit functor, after defining a model structure on $\mathcal{M}^\mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the index category we want.

However, in Hirschhorn's approach we define the homotopy colimit of the diagram $\mathbf{X}:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow \mathcal{M}$ in a framed model category $\mathcal{M}$ as coequalizer
$$\coprod\limits_{\sigma :\alpha\to\alpha '}\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}\rightrightarrows\coprod_{\alpha\in Ob(\mathcal{C})}\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}\otimes B(\alpha \downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$$
(where $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}$ denotes the natural cosimplicial frame on $\mathbf{X}_\alpha$) where the two parallel arrows $\phi$ and $\psi$ are respectively defined as:

- $\phi$ on the summand $\sigma :\alpha\rightarrow\alpha '$ is the composition of the map
  $$\widetilde{\sigma_*}\otimes 1_{B(\alpha'\downarrow\mathcal{C})}:\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha }}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}\longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha '}}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$$
  with the injection of $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha '}}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$ into the coproduct.
- $\psi$ on the summand $\sigma :\alpha\rightarrow\alpha '$ is the composition of the map
  $$1_{\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}}\otimes B(\sigma^*):\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha }}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}\longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha}}\otimes B(\alpha\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$$
  (where $ \sigma^*:(\alpha '\downarrow\mathcal{C})^{op}\rightarrow (\alpha\downarrow\mathcal{C})$ is the preocomposition wth $\sigma$ functor) with the injection of $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_{\alpha}}\otimes B(\alpha\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$ in the coproduct.

I see that these two approaches both try to "fix" the colimit functor, but I am missing the link between the two, and when and why one is more convenient than the other one.

Comment: In higher category theory, homotopy colimits satisfy a universal property just like usual colimits in 1-categories. When this language was not available yet, authors had to use different constructions to show that these things exist (in sufficiently nice cases). In homotopy theory, there is often a tradeoff between conceptual simplicity and technical simplicity — the first definition is clean but doesn't tell you how to compute anything, whereas the second is (at least in principle) a formula.

Comment: For comparing the two, the conceptually easiest way is via their universal property in the associated $\infty$-categories, but this introduces a lot more technical language. So a more hands-on strategy would be to show that the second construction is a derived functor of $\operatorname{colim}$, i.e. show that is has the correct universal property.

Comment: It feels the second definition can probably be obtained as a special case of the first one though. Using an explicitly chosen cofibrant replacement in a model structure for functors...

Comment: Simon Henry is basically right.  I would reccomend looking at Riehl's book on categorical homotopy theory or at Dwyer-Hirschorn-Kan-Smith's book on homotopy limits.  The explicit formula comes from computing the derived functor using a bar resolution.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you for your answer. So the two definitions actually coincide, but one is more formal while the other one is more practical. I agree that the most straightforward way is to show the second definition has the correct universal property, despite not being very friendly to manipulate. Do you know any hint or reference on the proof of this specific fact?

Comment: @PhilTosteson thanks for the nice references.

Comment: MikeTropper actually I like @SimonHenry's idea better to use the second construction as a specific cofibrant replacement to compute the derived functor. This is a much more low-tech way to deal with this problem than what I suggested.

Comment: @SimonHenry So you mean that we should prove that, in the category of functors (with model structure where weak equivalences and fibrations are componentwise weak equivalences and fibrations) we should prove that the diagram $$\coprod\limits_{\sigma :\alpha\to\alpha '}\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}\otimes B(\alpha '\downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}\rightrightarrows\coprod_{\alpha\in Ob(\mathcal{C})}\widetilde{\mathbf{X}_\alpha}\otimes B(\alpha \downarrow \mathcal{C})^{op}$$
is a cofibrant replacement of the diagram $X$, right? So that we get the thesis. Do you have some ideas on how to prove it?

Comment: The modern approach is to observe that both formulas are derived weighted colimits, with respect to the projective-injective or injective-projective model structure, respectively.  See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03266v6, in particular, Sections 4 and 5.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov great reference for my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\quad$The motivation of defining homotopy colimits is to restore the definition of colimits in some special cases. We can be aware of it in some easy examples:

- Let $I$ be a pushout diagram, it gives us 2 diagrams in $\mathbf{Top}$:$$D:=\ast\leftarrow S^n\rightarrow D^{n+1}$$and$$D’:=\ast\leftarrow S^n\rightarrow\ast$$
  $\quad$By $D^{n+1}\simeq \ast$ we can easily obtain $D$ is homotopic to $D’$, but $\mathrm{colim}\ D=D^{n+1}/S^n\cong S^{n+1}$, $\mathrm{colim}D’=\ast$. Then we find the problem: Taking colimit is not closed under homotopy.
- Take the diagram $X\overset{f}{\leftarrow}A\overset{g}{\rightarrow}Y$ in $\bf Top$. Now we consider$$\mathrm{hocolim}\ D:=[X\coprod (A\times I)\coprod Y]/\sim$$where the equivalence relation is defined by $\forall a\in A,\ (a,0)\sim f(a),\ (a,1)\sim g(a)$. And we call it homotopy colimit of the diagram. In this case, $\mathrm{hocolim}\ D$ has open covers $U:=X\cup A\times
     [0,1)\sim X$ and $V:=A\times (0.1]\cup Y\sim Y$. Meanwhile, the
  embedding map $A\hookrightarrow A\times (0,1)$ is a homotopy
  equivalence. This brings us a lot of powerful tools from algebraic
  topology, such as van Kampen theorem or Mayer-Vetoris. Now we
  consider another diagram by these two open covers:
  $X’\overset{f’}{\leftarrow}A’\overset{g’}{\rightarrow} Y’$. It’s
  obviously that thses 2 homotopy colimit are weak equivalent. There
  are several points should be noticed, such as the existence of the
  quotient map $\mathrm{hocolim}\ D\to \mathrm{colim}\ D$; and some
  algebraic topological invariants under homotopy colimit.
- Now we consider another diagram $A\overset{f}{\rightarrow}X\overset{g}{\rightarrow}Y$ with its homotopy colimit $A\times I\coprod X \times I\coprod Y/\sim$ where the equivalence relation is defined by $(a,1)\sim (f(a),0)$ and $(x,1)\sim g(x)$, hence it is homotopic to $Y$, and we note this space by $Z$. In the construction above, we glued $f$ and $g$ homotopically. There is another map, i.e. $fg$. So it’s naturally to add a new equivalence relation $(a,0)\sim g(f(a))$. But now the quotient is no longer homotopic to $Y$. And we just need to  simply consider the triangle $\partial\Delta^2$, and obtain $$A\times \Delta^2 \hookleftarrow A\times \partial\Delta^2\rightarrow Z$$

---

$\quad$Now we prove why the things we constructed  are the same as the derived functors of colimit.
$\quad$Consider the pushout diagram $D:X\leftarrow A\rightarrow Y, let \mathrm{Cyl}(f)$ and $\mathrm{Cyl}(g)$ respectively the mapping cylinder of $f$ and $g$. Then there are 2 natural embedding $i:A\hookrightarrow \mathrm{Cyl}(f), a\mapsto (a,1)$ and $j:A\hookrightarrow \mathrm{Cyl}(g), a\mapsto (a,1)$. Hence there is a new pushout $\mathrm{Cyl}(f)\leftarrow A\rightarrow \mathrm{Cyl}(g)$. We note this as $QD$, then $QD\to D$ has natural homotopy and $\mathrm{hocolim }\ D\cong\mathrm{colim}\ QD$.
$\quad$Now we construct the general $QD$: let $X: I\to\mathbf{Top}$ is a given diagram, for each category $I/i$(slice category), $U_i:I/i\to I$ is forgetful functor $(j\to i)\mapsto j$. Let$$(QX)_i:=|\mathrm{srep}_{I/i}(X\circ U_i)|$$Notice that $(QX)_i$ is the geometric realization of the simplicial space$$\coprod_{i\leftarrow i_0}X(i_0)\leftleftarrows \coprod _{i\leftarrow i_0\leftarrow i_1}X(i_1)\overset{\leftarrow}{\leftleftarrows}\coprod_{i\leftarrow i_0\leftarrow i_1\leftarrow i_2}X(i_2)\overset{\leftleftarrows}{\leftleftarrows}…$$**Definition**: let $T:I\rightarrow J$ be the functor between small categories. If for each object $j\in J$, category $j/T:=\{\mathrm{All\ morphism}\ j\to T(i)\}$ is nonempty and connected, then we call it terminal.
**Theorem**: if the functor $T:I\to J$ is terminal, then for any diagram $X:J\to \mathbf{Top}$, continuous map $\mathrm{colim_I}\ X\circ T\to \mathrm{colim}_J\ X$ is weak equivalence.
$\quad$Then it’s not hard to prove $(QX)_i\to X(i)$ is a weak equivalence and for each object $i$, $QX(i)\to X(i)$ is also a weal equivalence. And finally we obtain $\mathrm{colim}\ QX\cong \mathrm{hocolim}\ X$. Now we have proved the case $\mathbf{Top}$. For an arbitrary category, it’s pretty complicated to prove it, you can go check Quillen’s work.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the OP's question. The OP wants to compare two definitions of homotopy (co)limits, while this answer does not seem to compare two definitions in these special cases.

Comment: @Z.M Now I finished the answer.